Funnel in PowerBI
am struggling a bit with creating a Funnel view in PBI.
I have a series of 3 consecutive actions (1.a - 2.b - 3.c).
I build a code in SQL so that I got the CURRENT STAGE as of today for every observation, but that's not correct for a Funnel view.
I would expect funnel view of the type:
01.a ---base 100% (volumes 01+02+03)

02.b --- x%  (volumes 02+03)

03.c --- y% (volume 03)


Am not sure of the logic to build this, and if it's best dealt with in SQL of PBI DAX?
Thanks for your comments.
